# RTF doc to Excel

Tags: excel

I have several word docs (RTF) that have raw data in them that I need to get into Excel. Other than doing a ‘save as’ to text and importing each and every one of them, is there an easier way to import all the data into Excel?

These RTF docs are system generated and contain headers. There are no tables in the docs, but it appears to be set up in column and row format. I have seen some code examples, but I am unable to manipulate the code to get it to work for me.

Comment: Consider recording a macro while you import one. That will give you an idea of what the import looks like from a code standpoint. Then you will just need to figure out how to loop through files in a directory with a For loop and run that code over and over again in the loop.

Comment: Several? Seems like a manual import would be fine. Massage the data first in word to make it as table-like as practical. Try copy and paste and use the text to columns tools.